# Multiple oneOf conditions for different attributes

Tags: openapi, jsonschema

I'm looking at writing a JSON Schema that fulfills some key conditions.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "properties": {
    "person_id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "father_id": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "uuid"
    },
    "father_email": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "email"
    },
    "mother_id": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "uuid"
    },
    "mother_email": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "person_id",
    "email"  
    ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

1. I need the user to either enter a `father_id` or a `father_email`, not both.
2. I also need the user to either enter a `mother_id` or a `mother_email`, not both.

I was able to get condition 1 working with the code below, but I'm not sure how to add in the conditions for the mother.

```
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "required": [
        "father_email"
      ]
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "father_id"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support both, you'll need a `oneOf` for each set of conditions.  You have the one for "father" already.  Create another one for "mother" and nest them both in an `allOf`.

```json
{
  ...
  "allOf": [
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "required": [
            "father_email"
          ]
        },
        {
          "required": [
            "father_id"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "required": [
            "mother_email"
          ]
        },
        {
          "required": [
            "mother_id"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```